# Msbuild copying extra dlls from dependent assemblies

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains two projects, ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectA references ProjectB, so when I build the solution, ProjectB is being build first.

Lately, I had to use a nuget package in ProjectB. This nuget package contains two dlls; "Managed.dll" and "Native.dll" where the former is a managed assembly and the latter being a native C++ assembly. When ProjectB is being compiled, [a custom target](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) in the nuget package ensures that "Native.dll" (which is not directly referenced) is being copied to the output directory of ProjectB. When ProjectA is being compiled, "Managed.dll" is being compied to the output folder of ProjectA because ProjectB has a 'hard' reference to this assembly. On the other hand, "Native.dll" is not being copied, which consequently led to a runtime error.

My solution at this moment is to let ProjectA include the nuget package as well. I find that unsatisfactory since ProjectA does not need this nuget reference.

Is there an alternative way that will have both "Managed.dll" and "Native.dll" being copied to the output folder of ProjectA?

Comment: Use same output directories for both projects, or have a post-build in projectA which copies Native.dll as well?

Comment: Using the same output directory is indeed a solution, but then all projects need to have the same output directory. For instance, if I create a project ProjectC, which also references ProjectB, then the output of all three projects has to be the same. A post-build is also an option, but then I either have to keep track of the nuget assemblies myself or accept that I will copy all dlls in ProjectB's output directory

Comment: Yes as you noticed there is always going to be a 'but' as there's no way (afaik) msbuild can automatically guess all dependencies. Anyway we have a project with a similar structure and opted for the same output directory, applied automatically by having all projects import the same property sheet, and I'd do it again immediately as it All Just Works and is likely less hassle than any other solution.

Comment: For now I'm setting the same output folder on both projects, and if reuse becomes a problem in the future, I'll have to think of something else